# Determining IRQL level

Tags: windows, device-driver, irql

How can the IRQL Level of a piece of driver code be determined. PAGED_CODE() macro specifies that the piece of code can be run in an IRQL level less than DISPATCH_LEVEL.But haw can the exact IRQL Level be determined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeGetCurrentIrql` function   returns the current IRQL:

```
KIRQL KeGetCurrentIrql(void);
```

`PAGED_CODE` macro uses this function by the following way:

```
#define PAGED_CODE() \
    if (KeGetCurrentIrql() > APC_LEVEL) { \
        KdPrint(( "EX: Pageable code called at IRQL %d\n", KeGetCurrentIrql() )); \
        ASSERT(FALSE); \
    }
```

This macro should be placed to any pageable function, it crashes the driver in the case when the function is called at IRQL that doesn't allow paging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to set the Irql Level for a function?

Comment: IRQL is not a function attribute. Every function starts on the same IRQL as its caller. There are many ways to change current IRQL, like `KeRaiseIrql` and different synchronization functions.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Ive got the info I was looking for.

Comment: Note, this macro is useful on checked builds only. On a release build it's a NOP